# How to refactor an if statement inside of a match arm?

Tags: rust, refactoring

I've got the following method:

```
fn get_error_id(err: CustomError) -> i64 {
    let default_id = 0;
    match err {
        CustomError::Unknown(response) => {
            if response.status == StatusCode::NOT_FOUND {
                404
            } else {
                default_id
            }
        }
        _ => default_id,
    }
}
```

Is there any way to refactor it to inline `default_id`?

Answer (score 3):

Match arms can include `if` expressions, so you can simplify the code like so:

```rust
fn get_error_id(err: CustomError) -> i64 {
    match err {
        CustomError::Unknown(ref r) if r.status == StatusCode::NOT_FOUND => 404,
        _ => 0, // default_id
    }
}
```